# Float: left not showing up after a certain point

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

http://test.jptgraphics.com/products?cat=APPAREL

This works fine in Safari but shows incorrectly in the latest version of Firefox ( was fine in 3.5) and in some versions of IE.

In the middle column the product thumbnails drop down below when the 'float: left;' parameter is used. It is as if it is being escaped by a tag from that point forward no 'float: left's work and all the items are centered moving forward.

Comment: +50 for outsourcing your work to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sidebar_CAP:link visited active {
    background-image:url('../images/SIDEBAR_BG_BLUE.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

You are missing an apostrophe.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes its simpler than one thinks. I had validated the HTML but had not tried checking the CSS itself.  Thanks again. I can not vote this up yet but this fixed the issue.